# Error data type on typescript with next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I have a problem knowing the data type of the URL that I WILL res API from it, and I am using a custom hook to make it usable I am using `Next.js` with typescript

this is a `useFetch.js` (custom hook)

```js
"use client"
import { useState } from "react";

type FetchParams = {
  url: any
}

async function getData(url: FetchParams) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url.toString())
    return res.json()
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
}

export default async function useFetch(url: FetchParams) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  setData(await getData(url))
  return { data };
}
```

This is a pray components

```
import useFetch from '@/Hooks/useFetch';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Pray() {
  // Date methods
  let date = new Date();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  // day equal date - 1
  let day = date.getDate()-1;

  const [country, setCountry] = useState('eg')
  const [city, setCity] = useState('cairo')

  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const { data }: any = useFetch(`https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=${city}&country=${country}&method=5&month=${month}&year=${year}`)
    console.log(data)  
  }, [data])
  
  return()
}
```

error is:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'FetchParams'.ts(2345)

```js
const { data }: any = useFetch(`https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=${city}&country=${country}&method=5&month=${month}&year=${year}`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `useFetch` to consume a `FetchParams` type argument, not a string type argument.

Update `useFetch` to consume a URL string type value. Don't forget to use a `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect of making the fetch and updating the `data` state.

```js
"use client"
import { useState } from "react";

async function getData(url: string) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return res.json();
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error); 
  }
}

export default async function useFetch(url: string) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(url).then(setData);
  }, [url]);

  return { data };
}
```

Alternatively you could pass an object:

```js
type FetchParams = {
  url: string
}

async function getData(fetchParams: FetchParams){
  try {
    const res = await fetch(fetchParams.toString());
    return res.json();
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error); 
  }
}

export default async function useFetch(fetchParams: FetchParams) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(url).then(setData);
  }, [fetchParams]);

  return { data };
}
```

```js
const { data }: any = useFetch({
  url: `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=${city}&country=${country}&method=5&month=${month}&year=${year}`
});
```

The `useFetch` hook ***can't*** be called from within the `useEffect` hook's callback function. It must be called as the top-level of the component or other custom React hooks. Remove the `data` state and simply reference the `useFetch` hook's returned value.

```
export default function Pray() {
  // Date methods
  let date = new Date();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  // day equal date - 1
  let day = date.getDate()-1;

  const [country, setCountry] = useState('eg');
  const [city, setCity] = useState('cairo');

  const { data }: any = useFetch(
    `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=${city}&country=${country}&method=5&month=${month}&year=${year}`
  );
  
  return (....);
}
```

Comment: That will cause a issues for them as they are calling their custom hook in useEffect and we can't have a useEffect in a useEffect, hence will give error.

Comment: your answer is good but I have a problem in await because 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules becasue I use await inside  use effect

Comment: @RaoAsim Ah yeah, good catch, I neglected to look at the usage.

Comment: @AhmedEssam I see what you refer to and I've updated answer. Please check when you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to pass an `object` instead of a `string` to the `useFetch` as a parameter:

```
const {data}: any = useFetch({url: `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=${city}&country=${country}&method=5&month=${month}&year=${year}`})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you have assigned the interface to your object and then you are directly passing it value to it. Your url object is something like this:

```
url:{url:string} instead of being url:string
```

So you need to change your way of declaring the object or pass your object as a child object:

**Declare the url object the correct way**

```
 export default async function useFetch({url}: FetchParams) { 
 const [data, setData] = useState("")
 setData(await getData(url))
  return { data };
}
```

**Or send url in an object**

```
const {data}: any = useFetch({url: `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=${city}&country=${country}&method=5&month=${month}&year=${year}`})
```

Also I think your **useFetch** function is unnecessary here, you can just directly call your **getData** function.